# Generic/ global settings for plupload

Tags: plupload

How can I set generic/ global settings for plupload (http://www.plupload.com/) which should be used by all instanced created later on?

I tried to access "plupload.settings" but it does not exist.

Thanks :)

Corin

Answer (score 3):

I made it this way:

```
 var uploaderParams = {
     runtimes : 'html5,silverlight,html4',
     browse_button : 'select-images',
     container: 'upload-container',
     multipart : false,
     ... etc ...
 }
```

Then when I needed to initialize the uploader, extended the previous parameters (with the help of jQuery) with the ones I use for a specific uploader instance:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader($.extend(uploaderParams, {
    url : 'someurl',
    multi_selection : true,
    ... etc ...
}
```

I hope this will help you.